# how to get data inside object in typescript object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this object :

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "serialNumber": 555,
    "status": "xxxx",
    "createdDate": "2021-05-07T10:05:05.301+00:00",
    "employee": {
        "id": 1,
        "serialNumber": 1111,
        "firstName": "test10",
        "lastName": "test002",
        "role": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "USER",
            "description": "test"
        },
        "email": "gh@gmail.com",
        "mobileNumber": "00501",
        "country": "Palestine",
        "password": "$2a$10$pDJA4XL92TbEXEW2hiOlvOWxVj9j1wDNxPt8ArkSyQMIAjLJM6RxC",
        "name": "test10",
        "enabled": true,
        "deleted": false,
        "credentialsNonExpired": true,
        "accountNonExpired": true,
        "username": "gh@gmail.com",
        "authorities": null,
        "accountNonLocked": true
    },
    "invoiceHistories": [],
    "deleted": false,
    "employeeId": 1
}
```

How can I access customer data inside this object in type script and angular? I tried to write `response.employee => return object`

`response.employee.Id` => not working

Any idea?

Comment: Could be something simple as `response.customer.id` instead of `response.customer.Id`.

Comment: it was by wrong i did exactly `this.editStudentform.get('customerSerialNumber')?.setValue(this.invoice.customer.id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply return the response object and access it via response.id

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmbhgv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: u understand me wrong, i need the employeeId i wrote cutomer by wrong, so i need to print 1

Comment: sure, please refer to updated code here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmbhgv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this.

```js
const response={"id":6,"serialNumber":555,"status":"xxxx","createdDate":"2021-05-07T10:05:05.301+00:00","employee":{"id":1,"serialNumber":1111,"firstName":"test10","lastName":"test002","role":{"id":2,"name":"USER","description":"test"},"email":"gh@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00501","country":"Palestine","password":"$2a$10$pDJA4XL92TbEXEW2hiOlvOWxVj9j1wDNxPt8ArkSyQMIAjLJM6RxC","name":"test10","enabled":true,"deleted":false,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"username":"gh@gmail.com","authorities":null,"accountNonLocked":true},"invoiceHistories":[],"deleted":false,"employeeId":1};
console.log(response.employee.id);
```